# Why is Firefox so slow with a setTimeout animation?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Ok, so I have a small animation of snowflakes falling on the screen, and I used `setTimeout` to make it move. I love the way it looks so far (on Chrome at least), and right now, I'm working on cross-compatibility, and I'm looking at Firefox, and it's moving extremely slow. To be honest, the `setTimeout` function is set to 5ms, and it only moves 1px every 5 ms (a speed of 200 fps), but I need it to go at that speed. Is there some sly hack to get around it, and what speed is Firefox making the function repeat at? Also, side-note: it doesn't even work in IE9 (I don't care about <8). They moves for a second, hits the bottom of the screen, and then just stops (I want it to restart at the top).
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

My code (if you want to wade through it) if you don't skip to `"//begin actual function"`:

```
var width = window.outerWidth;  
var height = window.outerHeight;  
//foreground  
var curWidth = width - 90;  
var h2 = height * 5;  
var tbvar;  
function TB() {  
//random flake  
var flakeSrc = ['images/1.png','images/2.png','images/3.png','images/4.png'];  
var randImg1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * flakeSrc.length );  
var randImg2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * flakeSrc.length );  
var randImg3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * flakeSrc.length );  
var randImg4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * flakeSrc.length );  
var randImg5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * flakeSrc.length );  
//random horizontal position array  
var left = [];  
var one = 1;  
do {  
        one++;  
        left.push(one)  
    }  
    while (one <= curWidth);  
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * left.length );  
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * left.length );  
    var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * left.length );  
    var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * left.length );  
    var rand5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * left.length );  
    //////////////begin actual function/////////////////////////////////////////////  
    clearTimeout(tbvar);  
    tbvar=setTimeout(function(){  
        //find top positions  
        var top1 = document.getElementById("flake1").offsetTop;  
        var top2 = document.getElementById("flake2").offsetTop;  
        var top3 = document.getElementById("flake3").offsetTop;  
        var top4 = document.getElementById("flake4").offsetTop;  
        var top5 = document.getElementById("flake5").offsetTop;  
        //add 1  
        top1++;  
        top2++;  
        top3++;  
        top4++;  
        top5++;  
        //change top positions  
        document.getElementById("flake1").style.top = top1 + "px";  
        document.getElementById("flake2").style.top = top2 + "px";  
        document.getElementById("flake3").style.top = top3 + "px";  
        document.getElementById("flake4").style.top = top4 + "px";  
        document.getElementById("flake5").style.top = top5 + "px";  
        //end of screen statements  
        if (top1 == height) {  
            //top1 == "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake1").style.top = "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake1").style.left = rand1 + "px";  
            document.getElementById('flake1').src = flakeSrc[randImg1];  
        }  
        if (top2 == height) {  
            //top2 == "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake2").style.top = "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake2").style.left = rand2 + "px";  
            document.getElementById('flake2').src = flakeSrc[randImg2];  
        }  
        if (top3 == height) {  
            //top3 == "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake3").style.top = "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake3").style.left = rand3 + "px";  
            document.getElementById('flake3').src = flakeSrc[randImg3];  
        }  
        if (top4 == height) {  
            //top4 == "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake4").style.top = "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake4").style.left = rand4 + "px";  
            document.getElementById('flake4').src = flakeSrc[randImg4];  
        }  
        if (top5 == height) {  
            //top5 == "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake5").style.top = "-180px";  
            document.getElementById("flake5").style.left = rand5 + "px";  
            document.getElementById('flake5').src = flakeSrc[randImg5];  
        }  
        TB();  
    }, 5);  
}  
TB();
```

If you wanna see the whole project in action: http://fudgepants.com/snow/snow.html

The part I'm talking about is the large snowflakes, not the tiny ones.
Thanks!

Comment: Why on earth do you need 200fps? Cartoons look convincing at 24fps...

Comment: It would perform way better if you cache your selectors and abstract your code into smaller functions. Read about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: 200FPS? Your screen only goes 60FPS!

Comment: @Derek Ok, so I toned it down to 4px, every 20ms (50 fps), and it looks much more even, and not as choppy as I expected. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments on your code:

```
function TB() {  
  //random flake  
  var flakeSrc = ['images/1.png','images/2.png','images/3.png','images/4.png'];
```

Since that array is static, you should put it outside the function so it isn't created on each call.

```
  var randImg1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * flakeSrc.length );
```

`flakeSrc.length` will not change, so store the length and reference that. Also, you can replace `Math.floor` using the bitwise OR operator:

```
  var randImg1 = Math.random() * flakeSrc.length | 0;
```

.

```
do {  
        one++;  
        left.push(one)  
    }  
    while (one <= curWidth);
```

That seems pointless, and doing it on every call is just wasting lots of CPU cycles. `left` is only used for the value `left.length`, which will be the same value as `curWidth`.

```
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * left.length );
```

As above, `left.length` is used multiple times and is the same as `curWidth`, only slower to read.

And so on...

To avoid the global variables, consider wrapping it all in an immediately invoked function expression.

Comment: +1 for "immediately invoked function expression" (and _not_ "self-invoking").